# App not visible on Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I published my app a few days ago. On the first day, everything was normal, but since then, the app could not be searched on the Play Store app. It IS still searchable through http://play.google.com/store. What could be the culprit and how can I fix it?

What I have tried:

- Deleting Play Store app's cache

- Tried on multiple devices with different Android versions

More info:

- The STATUS in the Developer Console says "Published"

- Direct link works

Could not be found on Play Store app

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google play's search caching not showing the results soon enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that there's a problem with Google's search indexing. I renamed the app to something else, waited a couple of hours until the new name gets indexed, and changed back to the original name. Works like charm.

Comment: Right name matters. "title, publisher and app descriptions" should be good to show up in the device, otherwise, we need to use "my app name" to find it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20358487/984471

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot find app searching **on a device**, then it simply means Google Play finds your app incompatible with the device you are searching for it on.

**EDIT**

Your manifest lacks `support-screens` block. Add:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true" />
```

and see what the `supported device` count will be after that change.

Comment: It says that the app is compatible with my device. Strange enough, it was visible on the first day of publishing, and I haven't even pushed any new updates to it yet.

http://i.imgur.com/o877yov.png

Comment: What is "Excluded devices" in your dev console showing?

Comment: FWIW, I was able to find it w/ Nexus4 running CM10.1.

Comment: 0 http://i.imgur.com/1MeHsMK.png

Comment: Knowing that mine "supported devices" shows 3485 vs yours 1497 i still blame your app for being incompatible. Show your manifest

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="18"
I target Honeycomb and above.

This is what happens when I try viewing my app from the direct url. It can still be installed normally.
http://i.imgur.com/g7BzGlI.jpg

Comment: i wrote "show your manifest" not "tell me about your manifest" for a reason

Comment: Here it is: https://gist.github.com/puttio/6204302