# Google Play is not showing my app

Tags: android, google-play

I read many many posts on stackoverflow and I also went through many tutorials like Vogella and theNewBoston to see where am I making a mistake in publishing my app. 
I exported signed application of my package, created new apk and keystore. I believe that debuggable = false is not required to be set now. Eclipse automatically does that.
I can see my developer console showing my app as published however when i try to search google play on either my phone or pc, i cannot find my app. If only i use package name to search for my app, i can find it. my app is developed only for small and normal screen phones and not for tablets. I tried searching the app using numerous phones with no luck. 
attached here is my manifest. please tell me how to go over this issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.MyPackage"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <!-- These 4 lines have been added by user i.e me -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. added by me
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission android:name="com.MyPackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.MyPackage.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="API Key" />



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: FYI, this app has been published more than 48 hours ago

Comment: My app took a long time to show up. Hang in there!

Comment: @user1701593 Did it finally show up or did you had to write to google?

Comment: Hi user1701593.. Were you able to fix this issue as I am facing exactly same problem..

Comment: Hello, yes i was able to fix it..i have answered this question.. pl go thru it.. if u still dont understand let me know and i can help u out!

Comment: I am also facing exactly the same problem... Please help me.

Comment: @Gusdor "long time" - can you be specific?

Answer (score 16):

It took almost couple of days for my app to show up. Just a small note, if you cannot find your app in the play store, try putting the name in double quotes like "Park The Car" or "Relationship Guru" and then search it. Even when Play store started showing my app, if I just search with the app name with no double quotes, I could not find it. I saw almost 500 apps and still I could not find my app. But on using double quotes, I got a perfect string match.

Hope this helps. Thanks a lot for helping me with this question.

Comment: I am sure no user will add quotes when searching for an app. Check out Google's help for [App visibility & discovery issues](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329?hl=en#ts=3056739) even though it is not specific enough to be helpful. `When searching on Google Play, application search works across title, publisher and app descriptions. It's not easy to refine the search results appropriately when it comes to generic words that also happen to be brand names or titles.`

Answer (score 2):

There's possibility that the app that you're trying to search is not compatible with your device. That is why it is not showing up in your device. However, when you look up on the desktop site, it is visible. This is because, you are just viewing the app. If you will sign into you Google account, then you'll realise that when click the install button (on the desktop site) it will show you the devices that are associated with that account asking with their compatibility. 
Sometimes it is also that some apps are region specific and are not visible (due to the same reason)

Answer (score 0):

Put your app name in your description. Not just the title spot.

Comment: On Google Play I have filled all the mandatory fields including description and images..In this manifest I have replaced my original package name with something different..

Comment: and yes, my desciption contains the title of the app as you mentioned

Comment: OK but in "description" did you specifically put the name of the app not just in the title area?   posting as same time ignore this

Comment: yes.. my description starts with my app name.. For example - Gas Buddy is my title.. then my description reads - Gas Buddy is an application that helps you find..... etc is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. If it shows by using the com package name and your decription is filled out then you might need to send Google an email.  But just for fun double check Supported/Excluded devices under APK and when you search from your computer make sure you are logged out of gmail and chrome with any accounts linked to specific phones.

Comment: Yes RIck, i did that.. My app supports 1670 devices including the latest Sony Xperia z1.. I tried looking up for the app the way you mentioned.. No luck :-( ANy other idea?

Comment: Does your name have any special characters in it that would make googlebot miss it when indexing?

Comment: No, my app name is simple.. No special characters.. All i am having is special problems from google!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `android:label"` is correct in the manifest file. `@string/app_name` should be set to the correct name.

Answer (score -2):

Search my using your package name.

You will Find it.

If your package name is com.MyPackage.

Search as com.MyPackage in the Google Play Search Box.

It works Pretty Fine.

Comment: This does not answer the question.. the solution searched for is to be able to find it by name