# Published app not visible to play store

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I uploaded and published my android app on Google Play. But, I am not able to search my app by either app name  or package name. If I put app name or package name in search box of play store then it show message:

> We couldn't find anything for your search - com.app.flocam.
>   Suggestions: Make sure all words are spelled correctly. Try different
>   keywords. Try more general keywords.

If I search my app by using url like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.flocam), then I am able to search it.

What is the problem with publishing this app?

**Edited:**

**My app is live now but facing other issue on some device.
It gives message application is not compatible with your device when download pp from play store.
it is working on 4.x,4.x and 4.x but not working on 4.2 and 4.4 android versions.**

Comment: when you uploaded your application

Comment: This may be useful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169516/app-not-visible-on-play-store?rq=1

Comment: When uploading the app?
It takes time from the moment you upload your application until it is available in Google Play. In addition, check that Excluded devices is 0, and your Supported devices is full.

Comment: check configurations like country it should be visible and the devices screens. Its related to some configuration

Comment: as i mention in my question i am able to search app by url and i also able to download app from play store.

Comment: now my app is available to play store.i am able to search it by app name and package name. i don't know how is is working but it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

You uploaded your app on December 31, today. You just have to wait couple of days until it appears in the results of keywords search.

Comment: but it is available if i am searching by url

Comment: @rb16 Yes, but searching with keywords is a different search.

Comment: why searching with keywords is a different? Where is the documentation for this?

Comment: @MikiFranko Entering URL or package name is not really a search, it just goes to `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=package.name`. To make search by keywords fast, they need a preprocessing step, that's why it takes time, imagine how many new apps they're and how many existing. In the preprocessing step they are for example going through new app entry text and index words in it. So, if somebody writes "flocam", then they know quickly that app "FloCam" is related. I doubt that there is any documentation of this.

Answer (score 0):

Search again after 3-4 hours. you will be able to find your application.

Answer (score 0):

even if it does not show on app name search after waiting for 4 hours on publishing the app in play store, try to mention your app name in short description. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Im also had the same problem.

Just wait 48 hrs.after that check Again.
  And,
  this,in ur manifest.xml

```
<supports-screens 
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"  ``
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:anyDensity="true"/>
```